# TFS Alerts: What is the difference between "Server Item" and "Folder Path"

Tags: tfs, tfs-alerts

I'm setting Alerts on a TFS server, and I'm wondering what the difference is between these Alert settings:

`Server Item      Under      $/Some/TFS/Path
Folder Path      Under      $/Some/TFS/Path
Folder Path        =        $/Some/TFS/Path`

Answer (score 0):

Define alert filters in the same way you define query filters. The folder path can also include  your local folder path which different with Server Item.